# stagewebview calling local javascript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex4.5

friends.

I'm currently developing a flex mobile project. I currently need to load local javascript using stagewebview. Like:

```
var str:String = '<head>'+
                 '<script src="myLocalJs.js"/>'+
                 '</head><body>...</body>';
webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.loadString(str);
```

Is there any way to load local javascript using StageWebView? I'm not expecting an answer like 'There is a project called StageWebViewBridge' since it does't have all the features I need.
THX!!

Comment: Why you does not load an external URL? Problem solved.

Comment: With RichWebView u can't load a string but you can just open an html file with full communication between flash and JavaScript https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE

Answer (score 1):

you can use StageWebViewBridge to do this.... see how at http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/

THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

Due to security constraints the StageWebView cannot access local content (like using the file://).

You can however specify a js with a web address or inject the javascript itself as plaintext (rather than a .js file).